# cucumber declarative step definitions using web_steps.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

When using Cucumber for BDD (CS169.x1@edX) the following message is returned in response to execution of 'cucumber features/filter_movie_list.feature':

```
When I uncheck the following ratings: G, PG-13                 # features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:44
  Undefined step: "When I uncheck "ratings_G"" (Cucumber::Undefined)
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:49:in `each'
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:49:in `/I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/'
  features/filter_movie_list.feature:30:in `When I uncheck the following ratings: G, PG-13'
...
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

When /^When I uncheck "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

The particular configuration in question has a declarative step in 'features/filter_movie_list.feature' that says:

> When I uncheck the following ratings: G, PG-13

an attempt to implement the declarative steps in 'features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb' (to reuse the imperative steps of 'features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb') which looks like:

```
When /I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/ do |uncheck, rating_list|
  step "When I uncheck \"ratings_G\""
```

and a working 'features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb' file (i.e. the one created by 'rails generate cucumber_rails_training_wheels:install' after gem installation) with an imperative default step like:

```
When /^(?:|I )uncheck "([^"]*)"$/ do |field|
  check(field)
end
```

Also, it seems like 'features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb' is accessible to Cucumber since adding `When I uncheck "ratings_G"` to 'features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb' succeeds; anyone have any idea of what might be causing such behavior?  The implementation of the declarative step has even been simplified so that no variable substitution takes place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the course material which was provided illucidates the difference but did not lead us to delineate between two steps that are very similar; changing "When I uncheck the following..." to "When unchecking the following..." allows web_steps.rb to come back into scope and get executed as desired (the previously linked posting, [link: cucumber contradictory error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560114/cucumber-contradictory-error-messages), has more details).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried:

```
When I uncheck the following ratings: "G, PG-13"
```

Then in the steps file:

```
When /^I uncheck the following ratings: "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  puts "arg1: #{arg1}"
end
```

.. seems to work for me.

Comment: Does your 'puts' command trigger the use of the step which is already defined in 'features/definitions/web_steps.rb'?  In this case the class assignment is intended to direct us towards the same...

Comment: Well, it's been a few days and there aren't any replied so perhaps a link to another question (with more clarification) will help...

[link: cucumber contradictory error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560114/cucumber-contradictory-error-messages)

Comment: the 'puts' was just to debug what was coming into the step. So arg1 will have the value "G, PG-13". However, you should probably rename arg1 be more descriptive of what's coming in. I may have misunderstood but I thought your problem was getting a working step matcher that then let you capture the ratings and run tests on them ...

Comment: Yes, you understood the problem correctly and your suggestion was definitely a good idea (I was doing something similar by short-circuiting the variable evaluation and just trying to call the uncheck step with a constant); the solution as to what was the root cause is posted above and in the linked post...

Comment: Do you want to accept one of the answers if you've solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problem is with how you attempt to call a step from another step.

The second line of the code:

```
When /I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/ do |uncheck, rating_list|
  step "When I uncheck \"ratings_G\""
```

is looking for a step definition like:

```
When /^When (?:|I )uncheck "([^"]*)"$/ do |field|
  check(field)
end
```

Notice that it is looking for "When" inside the step regex. This unlikely exists, hence the undefined step error.

**Solution**

To call the step from a step you need to do one of the following:

1) Use `step` and make sure not to include the Given/When/Then keyword:

```
When /I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/ do |uncheck, rating_list|
  step "I uncheck \"ratings_G\""
```

2) Or if you prefer to include Given/When/Then, use `steps` instead:

```
When /I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/ do |uncheck, rating_list|
  steps %Q{
    When I uncheck "ratings_G"
  }
```

See the [Cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions).