# cucumber contradictory error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

[Problem Background: "cucumber declarative step definitions using web_steps.rb" Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525108/cucumber-declarative-step-definitions-using-web-steps-rb)

In troubleshooting the problem in question two contradictory error messages are arrived at; with the statement:

```
When /^(?:|I )uncheck "([^"]*)"$/ do |field|
  check(field)
end
```

added to 'features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb' execution of 'bundle exec cucumber features/filter_movie_list.feature' results in:

```
Ambiguous match of "I uncheck "ratings_G"":

features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:65:in '/^(?:|I )uncheck "([^"]*)"$/
features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:65:in '/^(?:|I )uncheck "([^"]*)"$/
```

However, removal of the step does not result in the step definition from 'web_steps.rb' being utilized; rather, a different error message is displayed:

```
When I uncheck the following ratings: G, PG-13                 # features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:44
  Undefined step: "When I uncheck "ratings_G"" (Cucumber::Undefined)
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:49:in `each'
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:49:in `/I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/'
  features/filter_movie_list.feature:30:in `When I uncheck the following ratings: G, PG-13'
```

How is it possible for Cucumber to complain that a step is redundant when there are two definitions in two places but then later complain that the very same step is not defined when its duplicate is removed?  Is it possible the second error message really means something other than what is stated?

PS:  The configuration was arrived at by way of a Cucumber installation with training wheels for CS169.x1 @ edX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have one definition called `When I uncheck "ratings_G"` that is somewhat matched with the call `When I uncheck the following ratings: G, P-13` that occurs in the error message. Cucumber is complaining that nothing matches the latter one. Does it exist in your code?

The *somewhat* matching would possibly explain the ambiguity warning you got initially. The definition matches but not what is found inside the string.

Comment: No... it's a good guess but if you check the "Problem Background" link at the very beginning of the post you can see that the "the following ratings" step is declarative and implemented by reuse of steps (so the problem as stated can't be made any more atomic); the issue is really why the web_steps.rb steps aren't being reused as the configuration would seem to allow as much...

Comment: hmmm - yes - I entered the wrong track there. Is the order of step definitions in movie_steps relevant? If the "undefined" step is after the "collection" step it may not be visible? Farfetched perhaps....

Comment: Well, seems like moving up the "when I uncheck" statement doesn't have much of an effect: leaving it in the file (above the implementation of the declarative step) results in the "Ambiguous match" error; removing it results in "Undefined step"...

Comment: And you are sure that your web_steps.rb is visible in the scope? A guess is that the ambiguity is between the two kinds of uncheck in movie_steps.rb and that web_steps.rb is not visible at all. Try to rephrase `When I uncheck the following ratings` to something different like `When unchecking the following ratings` and see if that works. (I have seen this before and I suspect that this behvaior changed between cucumber versions.)

Comment: Very nice Froderik!  My efforts to try to make the declarative steps as natural as possible should have taken into account what I already know, i.e. the RegEx can only match on a pattern and that duplicating a pattern can create confusion...  In this case the framing of the problem (some directions to "create a step like") probably threw me off...